# Firebase Session differentiation inside a function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-security

I have a single user USER_X. USER_X authenticates into my FireBase app, and then USER_X authenticates into my app a second time from a different location/device. They both authenticate using username/password.

If I'm inside a firebase function, how do I compare the second session with the first login and know that these are different devices/sessions?

I thought about accessing the token, but those appear to be short-lived and if they are short-lived then it could be the same session just an hour apart.

I'm looking for something that I can access from a Firebase functions and firestore rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DecodedToken` has a [`auth_time`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.DecodedIdToken#auth_time) property which is time in seconds since the Unix epoch, when the end-user authentication occurred. This can be used to differentiate between sessions unless user logs in on multiple devices at the same time.

> This value is not set when this particular ID token was created, but when the user initially logged in to this session. In a single session, the Firebase SDKs will refresh a user's ID tokens every hour. Each ID token will have a different iat value, but the same auth_time value.

Although this can be accessed only in callable functions (which are triggered by user actions) and not background functions such as Firestore triggers as background functions are not triggered by any user.

Other option would be storing the timestamp when they logged in local storage and reading it whenever necessary.

Comment: I get the database trigger comment. That was a bad and I will edit my question. Is this accessible in FireStore rules though? My use case is I want to attach some data to this session unique ID. I can attach it to a firestore record and as long as I can read it in the FireStore rules, then I can apply some logic on a per-session basis.

Comment: @Meeker unfortunately I don't think `auth_time` is accessible in Firestore rules. Although it is in realtime database. I'm not sure if a custom claim storing an array containing those auth_time will help you.

Comment: turns out `auth_time` is accessible in the rules. Just not documented. It seems firebase does not document every property, only one that it thinks people will use. But thanks! I would note that since it seconds I will probably combine it with UID, but it should work perfectly.